# Setting entity object from Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity

I have problem with creating objects from entities. I have two classes `Category` and `Product`. Here is their implementation:

```
class Category: NSManagedObject {
}
extension Category {
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var products: NSSet? 
}

class Product: NSManagedObject {
}

extension Product {
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var price: Double
    @NSManaged var producer: String?
    @NSManaged var basketConnection: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var containedBy: Category?
}
```

There is relation between them, where `Category` is in the `Product` table as a one of attributes. Now I want to add some data to this tables. There is no problem with adding `Category` ones, but I don't know, how to set specific `Category` to `Product`. I had to fetch all table with `Categories`, select specific object, and set it as `Product` attribute, or there is other way to do this? I haven't found any tutorial with this problem solving, so I had to ask here. Here is some code, which I wrote, to find out the solution (but it didn't work).

```
    let categories = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

    for cat in categories{
        let newCategory = Category(entity: categoryEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: ctx)
        newCategory.name = cat

        let newProduct = Product(entity: productEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: ctx)
        newProduct.name = "Test"
        newProduct.price = 10
        newProduct.producer = "Testowy"
        newProduct.containedBy = newCategory

    }
```

And my second question is, how to select specific array of Products, for specific name of category. Should this piece of code work?

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "containedBy.name == %@",arguments: [self.categories])
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Save first

You need to save the context before anything is written to the database.

```
do { try context.save() } catch {}
```

#### Correct Predicate

Your predicate starts correctly, but uses the wrong parameter.

```
NSPredicate(format: "containedBy.name = %@", aString)
```

The predicate for more than one category needs an array of `Category` objects (that presumably you have to fetch before).

```
NSPredicate(format: "containedBy in %@", categoryArray)
```

or if your categories have unique names, this also works

```
NSPredicate(format: "containedBy.name in %@", namesArray)
```

#### Other advice

Instead of `productEntity!` (which is a forced unwrap and needs more code) I recommend using

```
let newCategory = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
    "Category", inManagedObjectContext: context)
```